# Finding $A^{-1}=bA+cI$ with the eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A_{n\times n}$ (EDIT: $A$ is diagnolizable) and it's eigenvalues are $2,-3$, find an expression for $A^{-1}$ such that $A^{-1}=bA+cI, b,c\in \mathbb R$

My try:

Let's change the expression to a polynomial: $x^{-1}=bx+c\Rightarrow bx^2+cx-1=0$.

Using the given eigenvalues: $(A-2)(A+3)=A^2+A-6=0$.

So we get that $b=c=\frac 1 6$? Is it really ok to express $A^{-1}=bA+cI$ with a polynomial?

Comment: isn't A  a 2x2 matrix?

Comment: Using a polynomial is OK because all matrices involved commutate with every other. You can verify your final result by applying the matrix-polynomial to the eigenvectors.

Comment: @Babaxor it's $n\times n$ in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is not true as stated: Indeed, The matrix $$A := \pmatrix{2&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&-3}$$ is upper triangular so its eigenvalues are the values $2, -3$ that occur on the diagonal, but computing gives $$A^2 + A - 6 \neq 0; $$ correspondingly there are no $b, c$ for which $A^{-1} = bA + cI$.

---

In general, the constant term of the characteristic polynomial $p_B(t) := \det(t I - B)$ of the $n \times n$ polynomial $B$ is $p_B(0) = \det(-B) = (-1)^n \det B$, so we can write $$p_B(t) = t q(t) + (-1)^n (\det B)$$ for some polynomial $q(t)$ of degree $n - 1$. The [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) states that any square matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial, that is, that $p_B(B) = 0$, and so
$$0 = p_B(B) = B q(B) + (-1)^n (\det B) I.$$
So, if $B$ is invertible, or equivalently, $\det B \neq 0$, dividing and rearranging gives
$$B \cdot \color{red}{(-1)^{n + 1} (\det B)^{-1} q(B)} = I.$$
Thus, the quantity in red is $B^{-1}$, which in particular is expressed as a polynomial in $B$.

Note that the only features of $B$ we used in this construction are that (1) $p_B(0) \neq 0$ if $B$ invertible and (2) $p_B(B) = 0$, and both of these features also hold for the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) $m_B(t)$ of $B$ (the unique nonzero monic polynomial of minimal degree for which $m_B(B) = 0$), so one can analogously give for $B^{-1}$ a formula polynomial in $B$ of degree $\deg m_B - 1$, and by minimality this is the smallest degree polynomial for which such a formula exists.

---

Returning to our case, $$p_A(t) = (t - 2)^2 (t - 3) = t^3 - t^2 - 8 t + 12,$$ giving
$$A^{-1} = \tfrac{1}{12}(-A^2 + A + 8 I). $$ Moreover, $m_A(t) = p_A(t)$, and so this is the best one can do, i.e., there is no linear polynomial expression in $A$ for $A^{-1}$.

On the other hand, if a matrix $B$ is diagonalizable, its minimal polynomial is $\prod_k (t - \lambda_k)$, where the $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $B$, not including multiplicity. So, in our case, if we impose the additional condition that $A$ is diagonalizable, we have $$m_A(t) = (t - 2)(t + 3) = t^2 + t - 6$$ and rearranging $$m_A(A) = 0$$ gives $$A^{-1} = \tfrac{1}{6}(A + I),$$ and so in this case we can take $b = c = \frac{1}{6}$ as originally claimed.

Answer (score 3):

Transform to $I=bA^2+cA$, apply eigenvectors $v=vI=(b\lambda^2 +c\lambda)v$ resulting in $b\lambda^2+c\lambda=1$ for $\lambda \in \{2, -3\}$ and solve the set of linear equations $4b+2c=1$ and $9b-3c=1$. This gives you $b=c=\frac 1 6$ even without having to think about matrix polynomials.

Edit: As hinted by @Travis, this gives an easy way to calculate $b,c$, but does not imply on its own that $A^{-1}$ is given by $bA+cI$.

Comment: This solution implicitly assumes that $\Bbb F^n$ admits a basis of eigenvectors of $A$, which is not always the case (see the counterexample in my answer). This does prove the claim, though, in the special case that it does (equivalently, in the case that $A$ is diagonalizable).

Comment: @Travis Och, you are right. I've been trained to solve for unknowns, which I try to do regardless of the question.

Comment: to my upvoters: please consider to transfer the upvote to the more complete answer from Travis.

Comment: Thank you, but one can upvote more than one answer to a given question.

Comment: @Travis yes, but it still feels odd that, as of now, my incomplete answer has more votes than yours.

Comment: I believe I finished expanding my answer to address the nondiagonalizability issue after you received your upvotes. Anyway, there's enough noise in the system that I think one shouldn't worry too much about a small difference in upvotes for answers to any one question.